# How to make a caption of a figure (a), (b) split into 2 lines in a conference paper?

Tags: floats, captions

I am using the conference paper format, and my title caption is a bit long, I want to have the line go to the second line.

Not sure how can I do that?

I used `caption{}` in my other template, it automatically goes to second-line if the caption is too long without the need to do any setting.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{icad2020,amsmath,epsfig,times,url}


       \begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{minipage}[h]{1.0\columnwidth}
      \centering
      \centerline{\epsfig{figure=pics/fig1a-cropped.png,width=0.8\columnwidth}}
      \centerline{(a) Result 1 testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing}\medskip
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[h]{0.48\columnwidth}
      \centering
      \centerline{\epsfig{figure=pics/fig1b-cropped.pdf,height=4.0cm}}
      \centerline{(b) Result 2 testing testing testing testing testing testing}\medskip
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[h]{0.48\columnwidth}
      \centering
      \centerline{\epsfig{figure=pics/fig1c-cropped.pdf,height=4.0cm}}
      \centerline{(c) Result 3 testing testing testing testing testing testing}\medskip
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{Example of placing a figure with experimental results. Please use detailed figure captions that explain the figure well. The more modern way to include figures is to use pdflatex instead of latex and then to use 
    the \textbackslash\texttt{includegraphics} command with pdf files.}
    \label{fig:results}
    %
    \end{figure}
     \end{document}
```

Sorry, the `icad2020` file is here:

```
\newcommand{\permission}{
\begin{figure}[b]{
%\epsfigure{figure=./license-by-nc.pdf,scale=0.2}
%\includegraphics[width=0.05\textwidth]{license-by-nc.pdf}
\includegraphics[height=0.4cm]{license-by-nc.pdf}
\footnotesize
This work is licensed under Creative Commons Attribution Ð Non Commercial 4.0 International License. The full terms of the License are available at http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/4.0}
\end{figure}
}

%change default font to times-roman
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}

\oddsidemargin -0.15in
\evensidemargin -0.25in

\hoffset 0in
\voffset 0in
\topmargin -.5in
\headheight 12pt
\headsep 24pt
\footskip 0.3in
\textheight 226truemm
\textwidth 175truemm

\twocolumn
\columnseprule 0in
\columnsep 8truemm
\pagestyle{empty}

\def\ninept{\def\baselinestretch{.95}\let\normalsize\small\normalsize}

\def\maketitle{\par
 \begingroup
 \def\thefootnote{}
 \def\@makefnmark{\hbox
 to 0pt{$^{\@thefnmark}$\hss}}
 \if@twocolumn
 \twocolumn[\@maketitle]
 \permission
 \else \newpage
 \global\@topnum\z@ \@maketitle \permission \fi\@thanks
 \endgroup
 \setcounter{footnote}{0}
 \let\maketitle\relax
 \let\@maketitle\relax
 \gdef\thefootnote{\arabic{footnote}}\gdef\@@savethanks{}%
 \gdef\@thanks{}\gdef\@author{}\gdef\@title{}\let\thanks\relax}

\def\@maketitle{\newpage
 \null
 %\vskip 2em \begin{center}
 \vskip 1em \begin{center}
 {\large \bf \@title \par} \vskip 1.5em {\large \lineskip .5em
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}\@name \\ \@address
 \end{tabular}\par} \end{center}
 \par
 \vskip 1.5em}

\def\title#1{\gdef\@title{\uppercase{#1}}}
\def\name#1{\gdef\@name{{\em #1}\\}}
\def\address#1{\gdef\@address{#1}}
\gdef\@title{\uppercase{title of paper}}
\gdef\@name{{\em Name of author}\\}
\gdef\@address{Address - Line 1 \\
               Address - Line 2 \\
               Address - Line 3}

\let\@@savethanks\thanks
\def\thanks#1{\gdef\thefootnote{}\@@savethanks{#1}}
\def\sthanks#1{\gdef\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}\@@savethanks{#1}}

\def\twoauthors#1#2#3#4{\gdef\@address{}
   \gdef\@name{\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}\begin{center}\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
        {\em #1} \\ \\
        #2\relax
   \end{tabular}\end{center}\end{minipage}\hfill\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}\begin{center}\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
        {\em #3} \\ \\
        #4\relax
\end{tabular}\end{center}\end{minipage}}}

\def\@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{
   \refstepcounter{#1}\edef\@svsec{\csname the#1\endcsname.\hskip 0.6em}
       \begingroup \ifnum #2=1\bf\centering
          {\interlinepenalty \@M
             \@svsec\uppercase{#8}\par}\else\ifnum #2=2\bf
          \noindent{\interlinepenalty \@M \@svsec #8\par}\else\it
          \@hangfrom{\hskip\parindent}{\interlinepenalty \@M
             \@svsec #8\par}\fi\fi\endgroup
       \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}\addcontentsline
         {toc}{#1}{\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname} #7}
     \@tempskipa #5\relax
     \@xsect{\@tempskipa}}

\def\abstract{\begin{center}
{\bf ABSTRACT\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{0pt}}
\end{center}}
\def\endabstract{\par}


% Keyword section, added by Lance Cotton, adapted from IEEEtrans, corrected by Ulf-Dietrich Braumann
\def\keywords{\vspace{.5em}
{\bfseries\textit{Index Terms}---\,\relax%
}}
\def\endkeywords{\par}

\def\copyrightnotice#1{\gdef\@copyrightnotice{#1}}\let\@copyrightnotice\relax
\def\toappear#1{\gdef\@toappear{#1}}\let\@toappear\relax

%%% Strings for the preprint titlepage footer:

\newif\if@preprint\@preprintfalse
\def\ds@preprint{\@preprinttrue}
\def\ps@preprint{\let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo\def\@oddhead{}
  \def\@oddfoot{\rlap{\@toappear}\hfil\thepage\hfil
    \llap{\@copyrightnotice}\gdef\@toappear{}\gdef\@copyrightnotice{}}}

\if@preprint\ps@preprint
\else\ps@empty\flushbottom\fi

\def\thebibliography#1{\section{References}\list
 {[\arabic{enumi}]}{\settowidth\labelwidth{[#1]}\leftmargin\labelwidth
 \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
 \usecounter{enumi}}
 \def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus .07em}
 \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000
 \sfcode`\.=1000\relax}
\let\endthebibliography=\endlist

\flushbottom


%%%%% fancyheading included
\def\lhead{\@ifnextchar[{\@xlhead}{\@ylhead}}
\def\@xlhead[#1]#2{\gdef\@elhead{#1}\gdef\@olhead{#2}}
\def\@ylhead#1{\gdef\@elhead{#1}\gdef\@olhead{#1}}

\def\chead{\@ifnextchar[{\@xchead}{\@ychead}}
\def\@xchead[#1]#2{\gdef\@echead{#1}\gdef\@ochead{#2}}
\def\@ychead#1{\gdef\@echead{#1}\gdef\@ochead{#1}}

\def\rhead{\@ifnextchar[{\@xrhead}{\@yrhead}}
\def\@xrhead[#1]#2{\gdef\@erhead{#1}\gdef\@orhead{#2}}
\def\@yrhead#1{\gdef\@erhead{#1}\gdef\@orhead{#1}}

\def\lfoot{\@ifnextchar[{\@xlfoot}{\@ylfoot}}
\def\@xlfoot[#1]#2{\gdef\@elfoot{#1}\gdef\@olfoot{#2}}
\def\@ylfoot#1{\gdef\@elfoot{#1}\gdef\@olfoot{#1}}

\def\cfoot{\@ifnextchar[{\@xcfoot}{\@ycfoot}}
\def\@xcfoot[#1]#2{\gdef\@ecfoot{#1}\gdef\@ocfoot{#2}}
\def\@ycfoot#1{\gdef\@ecfoot{#1}\gdef\@ocfoot{#1}}

\def\rfoot{\@ifnextchar[{\@xrfoot}{\@yrfoot}}
\def\@xrfoot[#1]#2{\gdef\@erfoot{#1}\gdef\@orfoot{#2}}
\def\@yrfoot#1{\gdef\@erfoot{#1}\gdef\@orfoot{#1}}

\newdimen\headrulewidth
\newdimen\footrulewidth
\newdimen\plainheadrulewidth
\newdimen\plainfootrulewidth
\newdimen\headwidth
\newif\if@fancyplain
\def\fancyplain#1#2{\if@fancyplain#1\else#2\fi}

% Command to reset various things in the headers:
% a.o.  single spacing (taken from setspace.sty)
% and the catcode of ^^M (so that epsf files in the header work if a
% verbatim crosses a page boundary)
\def\fancy@reset{\restorecr
 \def\baselinestretch{1}%
 \ifx\undefined\@newbaseline% NFSS not present; 2.09 or 2e
  \ifx\@currsize\normalsize\@normalsize\else\@currsize\fi%
 \else% NFSS (2.09) present
  \@newbaseline%
 \fi}

% Initialization of the head and foot text.

\headrulewidth 0.4pt
\footrulewidth\z@
\plainheadrulewidth\z@
\plainfootrulewidth\z@

\lhead[\fancyplain{}{EVEN}]{\fancyplain{}{ODD}}
%\lhead[\fancyplain{}{\sl\rightmark}]{\fancyplain{}{\sl\leftmark}}
%  i.e. empty on ``plain'' pages, \rightmark on even, \leftmark on odd pages
\chead{}
%\rhead[\fancyplain{EVEN}{\sl\leftmark}]{\fancyplain{ODD}{\sl\rightmark}}
%  i.e. empty on ``plain'' pages, \leftmark on even, \rightmark on odd pages
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{}

% Put together a header or footer given the left, center and
% right text, fillers at left and right and a rule.
% The \lap commands put the text into an hbox of zero size,
% so overlapping text does not generate an errormessage.

\def\@fancyhead#1#2#3#4#5{#1\hbox to\headwidth{\fancy@reset\vbox{\hbox
{\rlap{\parbox[b]{\headwidth}{\raggedright#2\strut}}\hfill
\parbox[b]{\headwidth}{\centering#3\strut}\hfill
\llap{\parbox[b]{\headwidth}{\raggedleft#4\strut}}}\headrule}}#5}


\def\@fancyfoot#1#2#3#4#5{#1\hbox to\headwidth{\fancy@reset\vbox{\footrule
\hbox{\rlap{\parbox[t]{\headwidth}{\raggedright#2\strut}}\hfill
\parbox[t]{\headwidth}{\centering#3\strut}\hfill
\llap{\parbox[t]{\headwidth}{\raggedleft#4\strut}}}}}#5}

\def\headrule{{\if@fancyplain\let\headrulewidth\plainheadrulewidth\fi
\hrule\@height\headrulewidth\@width\headwidth \vskip-\headrulewidth}}

\def\footrule{{\if@fancyplain\let\footrulewidth\plainfootrulewidth\fi
\vskip-0.3\normalbaselineskip\vskip-\footrulewidth
\hrule\@width\headwidth\@height\footrulewidth\vskip0.3\normalbaselineskip}}

\def\ps@fancy{%
\@ifundefined{@chapapp}{\let\@chapapp\chaptername}{}%for amsbook
\@ifundefined{chapter}{\def\sectionmark##1{\markboth
{\uppercase{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth>\z@
 \thesection\hskip 1em\relax \fi ##1}}{}}%
\def\subsectionmark##1{\markright {\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\@ne
 \thesubsection\hskip 1em\relax \fi ##1}}}%
{\def\chaptermark##1{\markboth {\uppercase{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth>\m@ne
 \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ \fi ##1}}{}}
\def\sectionmark##1{\markright{\uppercase{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\z@
 \thesection. \ \fi ##1}}}}%
\csname ps@headings\endcsname % use \ps@headings defaults if they exist
\ps@@fancy
\gdef\ps@fancy{\@fancyplainfalse\ps@@fancy}%
\headwidth\textwidth}
\def\ps@fancyplain{\ps@fancy \let\ps@plain\ps@plain@fancy}
\def\ps@plain@fancy{\@fancyplaintrue\ps@@fancy}
\def\ps@@fancy{%
\def\@mkboth{\protect\markboth}%
\def\@oddhead{\@fancyhead\@lodd\@olhead\@ochead\@orhead\@rodd}%
\def\@oddfoot{\@fancyfoot\@lodd\@olfoot\@ocfoot\@orfoot\@rodd}%
\def\@evenhead{\@fancyhead\@rodd\@elhead\@echead\@erhead\@lodd}%
\def\@evenfoot{\@fancyfoot\@rodd\@elfoot\@ecfoot\@erfoot\@lodd}%
}
\def\@lodd{\if@reversemargin\hss\else\relax\fi}
\def\@rodd{\if@reversemargin\relax\else\hss\fi}

\let\latex@makecol\@makecol
\def\@makecol{\let\topfloat\@toplist\let\botfloat\@botlist\latex@makecol}
\def\iftopfloat#1#2{\ifx\topfloat\empty #2\else #1\fi}
\def\ifbotfloat#1#2{\ifx\botfloat\empty #2\else #1\fi}
\def\iffloatpage#1#2{\if@fcolmade #1\else #2\fi}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\rhead{\footnotesize{7-11 June 2020, University of Florida}}

\chead{}
\lhead{\footnotesize{The $26^{th}$ International Conference on Auditory Display (ICAD 2020)}}
\lfoot{}
\rfoot{}
\cfoot{}
%\cfoot{{\vskip 11mm}{\small ICAD2016-\thepage}}{}

% Define itemize
\def\itemize{\list{$\bullet$}{
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{5mm}\setlength{\labelsep}{2mm}
  \setlength{\labelwidth}{2mm}\setlength{\rightmargin}{1mm}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{1mm}\setlength{\parsep}{0ex}
  \setlength{\topsep}{2mm}\setlength{\parskip}{0ex}}}
\def\enditemize{\endlist}

% Define arabicenu
\def\arabicenu{\list{\arabic{enumi}.}{
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{5mm}\setlength{\labelsep}{2mm}
  \setlength{\labelwidth}{2mm}\setlength{\rightmargin}{1mm}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{1mm}\setlength{\parsep}{0ex}
  \setlength{\topsep}{2mm}\setlength{\parskip}{0ex}
  \usecounter{enumi}}}
\def\endarabicenu{\endlist}

% Define romanenu
\def\romanenu{\list{\roman{enumi}.}{
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{6mm}\setlength{\labelsep}{2mm}
  \setlength{\labelwidth}{4mm}\setlength{\rightmargin}{1mm}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{1mm}\setlength{\parsep}{0ex}
  \setlength{\topsep}{2mm}\setlength{\parskip}{0ex}
  \usecounter{enumi}}}
\def\endromanenu{\endlist}
```

Comment: Hi! Missing is `begin{document}`, the `icad2020` is unknown , instead of `\caption{...}` you use `\centerline` which not allows line breaks ...

Comment: @Zarko, editted my questions. Any idea what should I use instead of `\centreline`?

Comment: See my answer below. Your MWE is ancient, used solution are at list decade obsolete. Today for this use `\caption` , sub images usually enclose in `subfigure` environment (provided by `subcaption` package etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider what is written in the example caption! You provide MWE with one column document, but show example with two columns. Please in further consider to provide MWE which mimic final document as much as it is possible

Try the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,
               10pt,  % not needed, is default
               twocolumn]% shown example of your document has two columns!
               {article}
%\usepackage{icad2020} % unknown, for MWE not important
\usepackage{times} % obsolete
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % in real document remove "demo" option
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
   \begin{figure}[h]
   \centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.8\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pics/fig1a-cropped}
\caption{Result 1 testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=4cm]{pics/fig1b-cropped}
\caption{Result 2 testing testing testing testing testing testing}
\end{subfigure}
\hfil
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=4cm]{pics/fig1c-cropped}
\caption{Result 3 testing testing testing testing testing testing}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Example of placing a figure with experimental results. Please use detailed figure captions that explain the figure well. The more modern way to include figures is to use pdflatex instead of latex and then to use
the \textbackslash\texttt{includegraphics} command with pdf files (As i done now).}
\label{fig:results}
    \end{figure}
\lipsum[2-6]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Can I know what is the use of `\medskip` and `\hfil`.

Comment: @ann, `\medskip` add medium size vertical space between rows of images (or btween paragraphs), `\hfil` similar push  away images such that in horizontal centering environment distances between text borders and images and between images are equal.

Comment: thanks. May I know the value for `\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\linewidth}` is 0.48. I tried to increase to 0.5, but it does not work.

Comment: @nn, with `0.5`  you haw table rows to wide: 2 x =.5 + 2 x inter word spaces > 1, i.e. in row is not anymore space for images. This width had to be <=1..